# TypeScript: how do I properly type this tree node so that it either has a size property or a children property?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a tree node type.

```js
type Node = {
  name: string,
  size?: number,
  children?: Node[]
}
```

The idea here is that for leaf nodes, it should have a `size` property but no `children` property. For nodes that have children, it should have `children` property but no `size` property.

Right now I mark them both as optional, but in reality, they have an either-or relationship.

How can I tweak it to properly type such a node.

Comment: Use a union type?

Comment: I don't know if union type can be used to type the property, I know it can be used to type the values @caTS

Comment: You want `Node` itself to be a union, like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/w17Qym) shows.  Does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing? (Pls mention @jcalz if you reply to notify me)

Comment: @jcalz thanks I think the end results are what I was looking for. Just two more questions, 1. can we use `type` instead of `interface` here. Does it make a difference? 2. is it possible to make sure that a `children` property, if present, has to be a non-empty array? if it is an empty array, then it should be a leaf node instead. Anyways, I like to see your explanation about how you arrive at such a solution

Comment: You shouldn't really be expanding the scope of the question by asking followups in comments.  If these were requirements to begin with you should have put it in the original post.  Yes, you could use a `type` instead of an `interface`, [feel free to do that](//tsplay.dev/WKOryW).  The difference between type and interface is definitely out of scope here.  Yes, you could make it a non-empty array, [feel free to do that](//tsplay.dev/WJXr5N).  The difference between how `X[]` and `[X, ...X[]]` act is definitely out of scope here.  If you have further questions pls post them (after searching).

Comment: Anyway I will write up an answer here when I get a chance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for this to work, you want `Node` to be a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) where each member of the union explicitly contains one property and explicitly prohibits the other.  It could look like this:

```
interface BaseNode {
    name: string;
}
interface LeafNode extends BaseNode {
    size: number;
    children?: never
}
interface InternalNode extends BaseNode {
    size?: never;
    children: Node[]
}
type Node = LeafNode | InternalNode;
```

Here a `Node` is a union of `LeafNode` and `InternalNode`, both of which inherit from a common `BaseNode` type with the common `name` property (other common properties would go there).  The `LeafNode` type requires `size` and prohibits `children`, while `InternalNode` requires `children` and prohibits `size`.

Well, TypeScript doesn't actually *directly* support the concept of prohibiting a property.  Instead, you can say that a property is [optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties) (so it is allowed to be absent) and that its type is [the impossible `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type) (so you'll never find a value it is allowed to have).  That's as close as we can get.

---

Let's test it out:

```
const node: Node = {
    name: "root",
    children: [
        { name: "tooMany", size: 1, children: [] }, // error
        { name: "tooFew" } // error
    ]
}
```

Looks good.  The `"root"` node is okay because it has `children` but no `size`, and the `"leaf"` node is okay because it has `size` but no `children`.  On the other hand, the `"tooMany"` node produces a compiler error because it has both `size` and `children`, and the `"tooFew"` node produces a compiler error because it has neither `size` nor `children`.

Also note that you can treat `Node` as a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) as long as your check is to see whether the property is defined or `undefined`:

```
function processNode(node: Node): number[] {
    return node.children ?
        node.children.flatMap(processNode) : [node.size];
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUPksUgJbAAuEATgGYLIBCIUEAcgPYAmyBJ-SUJABcSKBWrkA5gG4iJAL7zi5KnQZIAMhBC1OPJBAAeVYFyhJmrfb2UCopLBFHAArmABGNOQJLwAFqQYXNQQwAD8LhAAbjR2SvyqNPSISACSlDSgGDaGJmHmlizs3La+xA5OkYIx3nb8AUEhYaI2ANoAuvF2FACeMMi5ALxaOnqlSAA+6ZnU2TZydvAcwOKCpa0TI3zlQs5IAETUHBwUBwA09X6BwaHAom1XvriC4PsHGGMXYo77AIxIBSXcoCF57UQHCgnACyIGAvW+lX+5yQjVuLSQnUBKIA9DjDNRjtQnqDXiJDlCOAAxCAAdwOgKQeIJRJJXX4SjstFcwHgFFIKyQMGOiCgUBsAApgBskDYAJQudxeahYna+UIUVxzdY8AB0aOawCQ4RJ-GleoNd11tAwIAosJgEuFHFF4tKcqQD3NEF1SI6PkUdkICiAA)